# Laravel 5 - Application::shutdown() function not found, is there any alternative solution?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Getting Fatal error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::shutdown() in laravel 5

Code example

```
App::shutdown(
    function () {
        // do somthing 
    }
);
```

Comment: And this error you get without any code?

Comment: It might help someone. In newer Laravel versions, you can use a [middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28340178/9618184) or a [service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57096102/9618184)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register a "shutdown" callbacks with Application::shutdown method removed in laravel 5
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/62ae860596f17a80954c106ff179288205a74d78

As alternative you can use

1) **[register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) php native function**

2) **Use laravel middlewares and implements Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\TerminableMiddleware interface**

You need implements

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
```

function for TerminableMiddleware interface. 
terminate function will be called at the end of the script.

For example laravel use **TerminableMiddleware** interface in **Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession** class to store session data at the end of the script

code example form source

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    if ($this->sessionConfigured() && ! $this->usingCookieSessions())
    {
        $this->manager->driver()->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, BTW it's `TerminableInterface` not `TerminableMiddleware`.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 is still beta software, so don't be surprised when/if things break.  You're likely getting that error because while

```
Application::shutdown(function(){});
```

was a valid way to setup an event handler for the shutdown even in Laravel 4, it's **not** a valid way to setup a shutdown event listener in Laravel 5.

This may be because Laravel 5 is moving towards an [annotated event system](http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-event-annotations), or it may be because of a temporary development glitch in Laravel 5.