# Laravel 5 shutdown function alternative

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Since Application::shutdown() function has removed, I'm looking for alternative which will assist me determine Laravel has finished, a moment before the end of the running.
Another thing which can assist me, is the last function that Laravel use.

Note: I don't need to register a callback, I'm building a profiling tool which need to understand Laravel done its run.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicated
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710642/laravel-5-applicationshutdown-function-not-found-is-there-any-alternative/27710747#27710747

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Laravel 5 the `shutdown()` has been replaced by [Terminable Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware#terminable-middleware)

This is middleware that is run *after* the HTTP response has already been sent to the browser.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\TerminableMiddleware;

class MyProfiler implements TerminableMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        // Do your profiling here
    }

}
```