# Catch Memory Exhausted error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to be able to catch the following error in laravel

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 201326592 bytes exhausted
```

I currently use the following script in the globals in order to catch other errors, but this specific error seems to bypass it.

```
App::error(function (Exception $exception, $code) {}
```

Thanks

Comment: Fatal errors can't be trapped..... that's what the "Fatal" means.... although you can set a `register_shutdown_function` function to handle a clean shutdown of the request

Comment: In addition to what @MarkBaker said:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339936/laravel-5-shutdown-function-alternative

Comment: @MarkBaker how and where should I register a shutdown function? An example would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The answer (as always) is in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).... something like `register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');

function shutDownFunction() { 
    $error = error_get_last();
    // fatal error, E_ERROR === 1
    if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR) { 
        //do your stuff     
    } 
}`

Comment: @MarkBaker do you think it could be an idea to throw an error which I could then handle from the already coded `App::error` in order to remain DRY? I don't know if you have any Laravel experience, but I was wondering where to place this piece of code

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Laravel has a built in method to handle php fatal errors:

```
App::fatal(function($exception){});
```

See more on the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-errors)

Thanks to @MarkBaker and @MateiMihai to help me understand better the situation.

Comment: Please be aware that you're in an "out-of-memory" condition when your code enters the shutdown function. That means you'll trigger another "Allowed memory size exhausted" as soon as you do anything that requires additional memory (almost everything).

Comment: @StefanGehrig do you mean that I should dump memory as first thing?

Comment: Yes. Some reserve a certain amount of memory when starting the application and release that reserved memory when running into these conditions.

Comment: Is there a function similar to this one in Laravel 5.4?

Comment: @mils I've copy-pasted my code inside app\Exception\Handler in the render function

Comment: @StefanGehrig I don't see any support for reserving and releasing memory based on memory usage built into PHP is there a good one that is undocumented as part of Laravel?

Comment: @SpencerO'Reilly I'm not really familiar with Laravel. But you can see an example of the process I described in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Component/ErrorHandler/ErrorHandler.php. Look out for `$reservedMemory`. They reserve 10k of memory when starting the error handler (it's just a 10k string). And then they release the memory in the fatal error handler.